# Returning An Array Value If it is Contain in String

Tags: php

How can I return the value of an array found in a string? Here is the code I have. But instead of the code returning "Power Supply", it returns "Others":

```
$string = "Summit 450W DC PSU FB - 450W DC Power Supply module for Summit switches";

$arry = array('Warranty', 'Software', 'Power Supply');

foreach ($arry as $word) {

    if (strpos($string, $word) !== false) {
        $catr2 = $word;
    } else {
        $catr2 = 'Others';
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to `break;` the loop after you found a word in it. Otherwise it will check the other words and don't find them, so it gets set back to `Others`.

Comment: add break - `$catr2 = $word; break;`

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123 and splash58, code now working I am grateful.

Answer (score 0):

For me, that code produces the correct output, but only coincidentally. I'm guessing you've simplified it from the actual code.

The problem is it will only work if the **last** item in the array is contained in the string. This is because you overwrite `$catr2` with `'Others'` every time an item in the array is not in the string.

What you probably meant to do was set `$catr2` to `'Others'` before the loop, then it will only be modified in the loop if it matches one item, otherwise it will remain at the default value.

Comment: thanks, but I tried placing the " $catr2= others"  before the loop as you suggested, it resulted in me having the last word in the array in all cases.

Comment: @bezaleelian You still need an `if` in the loop.